# how to keep foreground the same color if its been clicked

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

After the component has been clicked is should remain with a foreground of Color.BLUE regardless of any mouse actions in the future. How can I do this?

this is my code so far, I feel like I should be using  a boolean isntance variable to  tracks whether or not the component has been clicked, but not sure how to go about this problem. Help is very much appreciciated.

this is my code so far

```
public class IdeaMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    //instance      
    private JComponent x;

    //constructor
    public IdeaMouseListener(JComponent x){         
        this.x =x;          
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Set a flag to indicate that no change should occur

Answer (score 0):

Then set a flag which indicates the "clicked" state, use this to determine what should happen, for example

```
public class IdeaMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    //instance      
    private JComponent x;
    private boolean wasClicked = false;

    //constructor
    public IdeaMouseListener(JComponent x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        wasClicked = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!wasClicked) {
            x.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!wasClicked) {
            x.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a property of the listener to control the "clicked" Color of the component. Then you only change the color when it is not the clicked color.

Something like:

```
public class IdeaMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    //instance      
    private Color clickedColor;

    //constructor
    public IdeaMouseListener(Color clickedColor){         
        this.clickedColor = clickedColor;          
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Component source = e.getComponent();
        source.setForeground(clickedColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Component source = e.getComponent();
        if (!source.getForeground.equals(clickedColor)
            component.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Component source = e.getComponent();
        if (!source.getForeground.equals(clickedColor)
            component.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Note the changes to the code:

1. You don't need to pass in the Component as a parameter because you can get that information from the MouseEvent. So the code is more generic
2. Because the code is generic, the same listener can be shared by all components.
3. You know pass in the "clicked color". This is not necessary, but it makes the class more reusable because you can change the property of the class easily instead of hardcoding the value.